# Trigger Postgres Delete

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning SQL, and my teacher gave us that question.

Create a trigger (T_updates_stock_close) to not allow changing the primary key of the inventory close records. Display a message stating the lock and abort the process without allowing the change.

I wanted only one example of how to do it.

Comment: Asking homework questions is only ok if you show some attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the section in the official manuals covering [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html). Here is the part of the manuals covering writing [triggers in pl/pgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). PostgreSQL supports a range of procedural languages, bug pl/pgsql ships with it and is a good choice for simple triggers.

You will want to understand the difference between a "BEFORE" and an "AFTER" trigger, and in this case will want a row-level trigger. If I were you I would start off with a trigger function that just rejects *any* change on the target table and then step by step work towards your goal.

If that doesn't get you started and you can't understand the manuals take a step back and think whether a computing based course is the correct choice for you. The PostgreSQL manuals are excellent and there are a lot of resources available to learn from nowadays. If you have put in some serious effort and still can't get anywhere then computing might not be for you.